# Figures suppressed with plt.ioff show up later

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a module that loads data and makes plots. I have a bunch of test cases that run whenever I import my module. Some of them generate figures just so that I can inspect their properties. I suppress these figures using `plt.ioff` as a context manager. But when, in an interactive session (Spyder), I import the module and make some plots, the suppressed test-case plots appear.

A minimal example that demonstrates this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

with plt.ioff():
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4])
    
plt.figure()
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```

Two figures appear, one for each `plot` command. I get the same result in both Spyder and Jupyter. I'm using `matplotlib` v3.7.1.

[image: Both plots appear]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mistaken use of `plt.ioff`. The correct way to suppress a figure appears to be `plt.close`:

```py
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4])
plt.close()

plt.figure()
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```